# JSF Access to Beans

Tags: jsf, logging, javabeans, session-variables

I'm new in JSF. I use Eclipse and Primefaces 4.0. I have done a filter for my web application, it works, but... I have a page where I use a managed bean called Busqueda, and this bean is the controller of the this xhtml named BusquedaEmpleado. So, when I access from one session to this page with userA, this works perfectly, but if other user (userB) enters at the same time to this page, the bean has the data of the userA. Wich finally ends with a data table filled with the data of the userA in the session of the userB. How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that it are two distinct HTTP sessions (and thus you're not fiddling in 2 different browser tabs of the same browser session), then that may happen if you incorrectly store the session scoped data in an application scoped bean or as a static variable of a class. But this is a quite obvious cause. Perhaps it's time to take a JSF pause and learn basic Java and HTTP and web development concepts first?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm so ashamed, lol, actually I found the solution hours next I post this. You're right, my variables where static, I made them private and use a @ViewScoped for the solution. So, that fixed all. Thank's again and thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My variables where static, I made them just non-static and use a @ViewScoped for the solution. So, that fixed all. Thanks for the help. I hope it helps someone else.